# Join data from IQueryable and IList<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I'm trying to join a row of parent data to a related collection which has been squeezed into a single piece of data.

I have an `IQueryable` of Orders:

```
IQueryable<Order> orderList = context.Set<Order>
                              .Where("OrderDate >= @0", startDate)
                              .Where("OrderDate <= @0", endDate)
```

and a related `IList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` where each KVP contains the OrderID and a concatenated string of the product names from each Order Line.  I want to join the Value from the correct KeyValuePair to the Order info based on the OrderID Key.

To illustrate, the desired output would look something like:

```
OrderNum  OrderDate   Customer    State       OrderTotal   Products_Ordered
12345     12/12/2012  J.Bloggs    WA          $25.50       Bolts, Hammer, Suregrip Clamp
```

I am trying a linq join that looks like this:

```
IQueryable result = from o in orders
                    join line in orderLines on o.OrderID equals line.Key
                    select new
                    {
                      o.OrderNum
                      o.OrderDate,
                      o.Customer.CustomerFullName,
                      o.DeliverAddress.State,
                      o.TotalPrice,
                      line.Value
                    }
```

The method performing the join seems to work, but when I access the returned `IQueryable`, I get a `NotSupportedException`:  *Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Yes, tags updated

Comment: Yep, I noticed right after I asked, that you had `context.Set<Order>`. Thanks.

Comment: Your variable `result` is of type `IQueryable`. Is that required for some reason, or do you just want the actual results, and this happens to be what they come as?

Comment: Why do you have an `IList<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`? Wouldn't it be better to have a dictionary?

Comment: No reason, except the original data in the parent is an IQueryable, and as this is a request for additional info, I thought it best (and easiest) to use the same construct.  I think the only requirement is that it is IEnumerable.

Comment: Also, regarding the problem you're having: I'd bet if you materialized your `IQueryable` by doing `ToList` or `ToArray`, you wouldn't have this problem. It's probably trying to construct SQL to match your LINQ query. Could you try `from o in orders.ToArray()`?

Comment: @Asad, I don't know if it would be better, or how it makes a difference.  I started with a KeyValuePair, and then realised I needed a list of them.

Comment: @mcalex If you had a dictionary, it would already be indexed by key and you could do `orderLines[o.Key]` where you have `line.Value` without having to do any joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IQueryable` is actually a specialized entity framework implementation that, when iterated, attempts to construct an SQL query by examining an expression tree, execute this query, and return an enumerable over the results. This is fragile, and your projections and queries can't be arbitrarily complex, or the expression -> SQL converter has no idea what to do with it.

Fixing this by materializing your `IQueryable` first is fine, but you don't even really need to do that. Why have a list of what is essentially tuples, when what you want is a dictionary that maps the order ID to a bunch of data?

```
IDictionary<int, string> orderLines = new Dictionary<int, string>();

// Add a dummy item
orderLines[1234] = "Hello, this, is, a, test";

// Get your combined view
// Assuming you have an order with 1234 as the ID, this should work
var result = from o in orders
             select new
             {
                 o.OrderNum
                 o.OrderDate,
                 o.Customer.CustomerFullName,
                 o.DeliverAddress.State,
                 o.TotalPrice,
                 Products = orderLines[o.OrderID]
             }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. mixing the linq to object with linq to sql wouldn't work in any condition as far as ef's query construction is concerned.

Comment: the "orderLines[o.OrderID]" line is being marked with 'Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access'.  I changed the line to:  Products = orderLines[o.OrderID].  Does this make sense?

Comment: @mcalex Yeah, sorry. That's correct, you need to explicitly give the property a name in the anon type. Does it work?

Comment: @Asad yep, it's working, except for the return type.  I moved the creation of the new data into it's own method and I don't know how to return an IEnumerable<AnonymousType>

Comment: If you actually need to return this and pass it around, you need to make a proper class that can hold this data. It should have all those properties from `order` as well as a `Products` property. Make a new one of those in the LINQ query instead of an anonymous type, and make the return type an enumerable of that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just change the return type to `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Comment: @mcalex Anonymous type can not be exposed outside their declaring function.

Comment: IEnumerable<dynamic> to the rescue.  Thanks @Asad

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework has issues with some types, because it tries to push them to the backing database. The quick and easy solution is to pull the data down before performing the join.

```
var orderList = context.Set<Order>
                       .Where("OrderDate >= @0", startDate)
                       .Where("OrderDate <= @0", endDate)
                       .ToList(); // ------> Relevant line <------

var result = from o in orderList
             join line in orderLines on o.OrderID equals line.Key
             select new
             {
                 o.OrderNum
                 o.OrderDate,
                 o.Customer.CustomerFullName,
                 o.DeliverAddress.State,
                 o.TotalPrice,
                 line.Value
             };
```

It's just a change in where the joining happens, RDBMS- or client-side.

Performance won't be an issue, assuming you don't have a ton of data and all rows will be matched. Of course, you will have to pull down data that doesn't get joined, so if only a few of `orderList` will be in `result`, that might be worth a second thought, design-wise. The only alternative would be in pushing the `KeyValuePair` items to the server first, which probably isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it EF having issues, it's a pretty conscious design decision. As long as you're working with `IQueriable`, you're injecting text into the query string itself -- it's what being `IQueriable` means!

Comment: Tried this, but I've moved the code to it's own method and I'm not entirely sure how to identify the return type.  IEnumerable requires a Type parameter and the result is not a System.Linq.Enumerable.  How do i indicate an IEnumerable<Anonymous>?

Comment: @mcalex As a general rule, once you have to take data out of a method, you should create a concrete type. Aside from that, you'll need to use `dynamic` or some other form of reflection, but you'll be losing static type checking, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Joining a query result (`IQueryable`) with a normal enumerable stored in memory (`IEnumerable<...>`) doesn't make much sense. Think about it, the query doesn't get processed until it's materialized, injecting your own data in queries is done in the query text itself -- that's not what you really want, now is it?

I think what you expect from this is best achieved by first materializing the `IQueryable` into an `IEnumerable<>`, then doing a plain LINQ join on two `IEnumerable<>`s, which is trivial.

It's not like you'd be using the `IEnumerable<>` to filter the result set on the server side, you're not really losing any performance here.

**Edit:** Note that if you *are* using the `IEnumerable<>` to filter the results on the server side, you *can* do that! EF (I assume that's what you're using) has very strong special cases for things like `IQueriable<>.Any<>()` with an `IEnumerable<>.Contains<>()` inside it -- it inserts the literal values in the query text. It's just the actual join that doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware the query doesn't get processed until it's materialized.  That makes sense of the problem for me.  Many thanks

Comment: I generally find that looking at the generated query text is extremely educational. Give it a try to see how it works internally, it will make EF a lot more intuitive to use!